# How or can I bypass the command block character limit on singleplayer. (1.12.2)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a written book command full of op items but unfortunately I'm stuck because of this problem.

Comment: Have you tried functions since they don't really have a max lenght? As far as I know, there is a limit to command lenght due to memory limitations, not an option; thus you can't really get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Creat a [function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nv_qGA3Xd_4) with the command in it and run it from your game to get the item.

Functions do not have a character limit, instead they have a commands limit (which is pretty big).

Answer (score 0):

Just split it into two commands. Half the items in one, half in the other.